# ¿Como hacer una paginación en angular 2 con una api en rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Estoy haciendo un blog en angular 2 con rails como api, estoy tratando que de 15 id, es decir 15 post solo aparezcan 5 en la pagina principal al darle a un buttom me aparezca las otras 5 entradas ejemplo

index = 5 entradas 
al darle al buttom me muestre las entradas 6 a 10
al darle click otra vez aparezca 11 a 15

Comment: Hola Ramiro, por favor edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía _"[ask]"_ y agrega un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender qué estás haciendo y qué problema o error estás enfrentando. Si buscas ideas, opiniones, sugerencias o recomendaciones, busca _"paginación con angular2"_ en Google.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es utilizando alguna gema para tu API de Rails; en particular te recomiendo [**api-pagination**](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination).

Para instalarla, debes agregar esa gema, junto con alguna otra específica para paginación (e.g. [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)), en tu archivo *Gemfile*:

```
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'api-pagination'
```

Y para utilizara agrega `paginate` (en lugar de `render` o `redirect_to`) en el *endpoint* de tu controlador, por ejemplo:

```
def index
  posts = Post.all

  paginate json: posts, per_page: 5
end
```

Por último, sólo debes agregar el parámetro `page` en el *querystring* del *endpoint* cuando lo llames desde *angular*, por ejemplo:

```
www.miapp.com/api/v1/posts?page=1
```

Además, a través del encabezado *Link* de la solicitud, recibirás la información que necesitas para crear los enlaces para **siguiente página** (i.e. *next*), **página anterior** (i.e. *prev*), **primer página** (i.e. *first*) y **última página** (i.e. *last*), por ejemplo:

```
# Link: <http://www.miapp.com/api/v1/posts?page="2">; rel="next",
# <http://www.miapp.com/api/v1/posts?page="3">; rel="last",
# <http://www.miapp.com/api/v1/posts?page="1">; rel="first",
# <http://www.miapp.com/api/v1/posts?page="1">; rel="prev",
```